# why I am updating nested cookie in client and it corrupt the cookie keys/values on the server?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am using ASP Net C#.
I have nested cookie that I am updating in client.
my cookie : 
OwnerId=2027&LastAppId=2203&AppType=4&Mail=simba@w.l
js :

```
var cookieName = "LastAppId"
 var lastAppId = jQuery.getNestedCookie("myCookie", cookieName);
        var lastQryAppId = "&" + cookieName + "=" + lastAppId;
        var currentQryAppId = "&" + cookieName + "=" + newAppId;
        var newFullCookieStr = fullCookie.replace(lastQryAppId, currentQryAppId);
        jQuery.cookie("myCookie", newFullCookieStr, { expires: 360, path: '/' });
```

C#:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"].Value ="OwnerId%3D2027%262LastAppId%3D2203%26AppType%3D4%26Mail%3Dsimba%40w.l"
```

but I cant get it by name beacause all keys are gone .

```
(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["2min_Auth"].Values).AllKeys[0] = null;
```

i know I can take the string value and substring it or split and get the values but  is any one know why its happen and how can I return the keys/values to work again ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("OwnerId%3D2027%262LastAppId%3D2203%26AppType%3D4%26Mail%3Dsimba%40w.l");
NameValueCollection nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.there is no way to fix the cookie it self?